# Trouble finding the area

Tags: geometry

This question appears in a kid's math book.  Am I missing some obvious answer?

I can't find a way to draw a line that divides the area evenly.

[image]

Comment: Hint:  a diagonal divides a rectangle into two equal parts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any line between the red ones cuts the total area in half. The simplest case would be a vertical line.

[image]

Comment: So yes, I was missing something obvious!   Thank you!

Comment: In fact both red lines can be rotated further about their intersection: the one with positive slope until it reaches a slope of $\frac{2}{3}$, and the one with negative slope until it reaches a slope of $\frac{-4}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way it could be done.

Notice in the picture, if we were to ignore the blue squares, the rest of the image has 2-fold rotational symmetry and so any line which passes through the centre of rotation will bisect it.
[image]

In particular if we choose the diagonal line from top left to bottom right, we see that this will put two of the blue squares above the line and two of them below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the instructions don't permit moving the squares around

Comment: @nuggethead You don't have to move any squares around, the red line above bisects the area of the shape. The rest is just a proof of that fact.